# Automatically scaling game graphics to maintain at least 60 fps

Tags: graphics

I have noticed that several graphics settings in games rely on a restart of the game to take effect, having that said, would it be technically possible to make a game read the computers specs and automatically and dynamically scale the games graphics settings live, so that the game always maintains at least for example 60 fps. I'm thinking of games like MMO:s where you might get fps drops if there are more people running around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

First of all: reading the hardware is not enough, programs could interfere as well (use CPUs)

Then, even when you know (and are able to predict) the CPU usage, there could be so little CPU time left that 60 FPS is just not within reach